# How can I automatically interpolate n intermediate values for a CSS property given an upper and lower bound?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, interpolation, linear-interpolation

If I have some media queries that set a value based on the current screen width **how can I automate the computation of n intermediate steps**?

As example: if I had a top value of 50% at 1080p and a value of 32% at 2160p I should be able to compute 4 intermediate steps:

```css
@media(min-height: 1080px) {
  top: 50%;
}
@media(min-height: 1350px) {
  top: 45.5%;
}
@media(min-height: 1620px) {
  top: 41%;
}
@media(min-height: 1890px) {
  top: 36.5%;
}
@media(min-height: 2160px) {
  top: 32%;
}
```

**I'm interested in any sort of possible solution: pure CSS, Sass, JS, etc.**

(Also, could this kind of computation be possible for non linear values?)

Comment: Why are you thinking of using media queries rather than just calclulating on the fly?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How to interpolate between two values? What have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: @TylerH given the boundaries and the number of steps I'd like to compute at least the evenly spaced values, so given 10 and 20 with 2 steps in between at least 10, 13.3, 16.6 and 20

Comment: @AHaworth to be honest, I think I already saw some solution involving custom properties and media queries in some tutorial, but I don't remember if and when I saw it

Comment: @Thomas yes, this question is about what different methods could be used to solve an interpolation problem in css (a stricter definition is being defined with TylerH questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a mixin to generate the steps, it would be a basic `@for` loop.
Depending on the flexibility you want for the mixin you'll need few arguments:

- `$stepsNb`
- `$minWidthQuery`
- `$maxWidthQuery`
- `$property`
- `$minValue`
- `$maxValue`

Then the mixin will calculate the steps for you:

```css
@mixin interpolateSteps($stepsNb: 5, $minWidthQuery: 1080px, $maxWidthQuery: 2160px, $property, $minValue, $maxValue) {
    $step: ($maxWidthQuery - $minWidthQuery) / ($stepsNb - 1);
    $stepValue: ($maxValue - $minValue) / ($stepsNb - 1);
    
    @for $i from 0 to $stepsNb {
        @media(min-height: $minWidthQuery + ($step * $i)) {
            #{$property}: $minValue + ($stepValue * $i);
        }
    }    
}
```

You would use it like this:

```css
.foobar {
    @include interpolateSteps($property: top, $minValue: 50%, $maxValue: 32%);
}
```

And it would output:

```css
@media (min-height: 1080px) {
  .foobar {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-height: 1350px) {
  .foobar {
    top: 45.5%;
  }
}
@media (min-height: 1620px) {
  .foobar {
    top: 41%;
  }
}
@media (min-height: 1890px) {
  .foobar {
    top: 36.5%;
  }
}
@media (min-height: 2160px) {
  .foobar {
    top: 32%;
  }
}
```